# Java priority based udp protocol

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I try to develop simple mmorpg.Since there are 2 priorities of data to be sent, one is the TCP based information that must be sent from the server and the other is UDP based as character movement is there a way to setup UDP protocol to be able to work also as TCP depending of package priority?So there would be no need to open 2 connections from server to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking if it is possible to replace a TCP bytestream and a UDP "stream" of messages with something implemented just using UDP.

The answer is: "Yes in theory, but in practice it would be a lot of work, would perform poorly, and would achieve very little".

TCP is a reliable byte stream protocol that is implemented on top of an unreliable IP packet layer by keeping track of what has been sent and what has been acknowledged.  If specific packets get lost / dropped by the network, the sender or receiver notice and the missing data gets retransmitted.  TCP also implements flow control so that the protocol does not overload the network.

By contrast, UDP does not provide either reliability or flow control.

It would be possible to implement TCP-like reliability and flow control over any unreliable packet layer ... including UDP/IP.  However, to do this in Java, you would need to implement a TCP-like protocol in a "user-space" application library on both the client and server sides.  That is a lot of work, and the performance would inevitably be inferior to a real TCP/IP implementation in the OS kernel.

Besides, while you are eliminating TCP/IP sockets, you are replacing them with equivalent data structures and buffering in the Java application itself.  In practice, this is unlikely to save resources on either server or client side.

Comment: So you suggest me to open both tcp and udp protocols ?

Comment: If your application requires both, then yes.